# The best way to pass a Point array between activities and save it in SQLite

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am doing a "drawing-like" project which enables users to draw a path in ActivityB and then get a clipped photo when back to ActivityA, in which they can choose to save it for editing again next time.

The most important and the only information should be passed/saved is the (x,y) points user draws. I use two float arrays to store the value, and pass them as extra to ActivityA. (both of the float[] has a limited size, 500.)

```
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_X", xPoints);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_Y", yPoints);
```

When saving into SQLite, I save two Strings converted from the float[] because SQLite doesn't support saving an array.

```
private String floatArrToStr(float[] arr) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        s.append(arr[i]);
        s.append(",");
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

My question is, is this the best way to pass and save Points? Will using Parcelables be better ([Android: Pass List<GeoPoint> to another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141944/android-pass-listgeopoint-to-another-activity))?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Serializable` across activities.

```
Class PathPoint implements Serializable {
  public float x;
  public float y;
}
```

then `ArrayList<PathPoint>` is also Serializable, can be placed into a `Bundle` and sent across.

Comment: As far as I know, `Serializable` is standard in JAVA but not suitable for Android due to efficiency

Comment: [Benefit of using Parcelable instead of serializing object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5551155/1390612)

Comment: @tiddan quote from same link: "Parcelable is not meant to be passed to an activity."

Comment: You can pass a Parcelable between activities. In [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
search for `putExtra (String name, Parcelable value)`

Comment: when to use serializable instead of Parceable?

Comment: @RajuGujarati `Parcelable` is high performance, specially when two processes exchange data remotely. For most _within the same app_ scenarios, `serializable` will suffice.