# Parcelable for pass a List<object> between two activity

Tags: android, list, android-activity, parcelable

Im searching for a way to pas a List between two activity
and I found 2 ways
perefering the faster one Parcelable
but every page I read can not found how to convert my list to Parcelable or
initialize initialize with my list values
or how to recieve the list in second activity
can anyone =new a tutorial's link or code the Parcelable class and the section of sending intent in first and recieving in second activity
tnx
notice: its a List not Arraylist

Comment: In Android `List` is an interface (you can't instantiate it), so most probably you are working with something that implements it (such as `ArrayList`). Anyway - check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141944/android-pass-listgeopoint-to-another-activity